# How can I conditionally hide dynamic web content from read-later services (ie Instapaper, Pocket)?

Tags: html, css, instapaper, pocket

I'm building a single-page website that contains a javascript "calculator" that let's users input custom values and see an output immediately.

I don't expect this to work if my page is scraped by a service like instapaper for users to read later from a kindle (for example).

Is there a way for me to show a conditional message for these users (like "visit example.com for the full calculator") or to hide this section entirely?

Comment: @ManofSnow That makes no sense at all.

Comment: @ManofSnow maybe I didn't explain it well enough... I want to conditionally hide a block of HTML

Answer (score 1):

### Opting Out

Most read later services offer ways of blocking your site from their *read later* functions. Here are the links for the most common ones:

- Instapaper: http://www.instapaper.com/publishers
- Readability: [http://help.readability.com/customer/...](http://help.readability.com/customer/portal/articles/267462-how-can-i-opt-out-of-readability-view-)
- Pocket: [http://help.getpocket.com/customer/port...](http://help.getpocket.com/customer/portal/emails/new) *(couldn't find the specific page, so this is just the "contact us" page)*

### Specifying content to be displayed

- Pocket: *[No specific guidelines.](http://help.getpocket.com/customer/portal/questions/338763-any-specific-pocket-friendly-markup-i-should-know-about-)*
- Instapaper: They use [the Open Graph Protocol](http://ogp.me/) *(doesn't really tell you how to remove content though)*
- Readability: [Article Publishing Guidelines](https://www.readability.com/developers/guidelines/#reader) *(very easy to understand)*

Comment: +1, thanks @hitecherik. In this case thoygh, I only want to block a portion of a page, like a single div (in this case, my "calculator" section). I dont want to block my entire site--in fact, I'd like to encourage instapaper use for the rest of the page. If you can explain how to do that with the docs you linked to, I'll accept this answer.